# Groovy: Get a specific value in a file

Tags: groovy, split

I'm quite new in Groovy.
Basically I load a text file, then I need to get a specific value at one line (actually the 6th).

The line is like:
`STATIC_ASSERT(VERSION == 888888, "blablabla");`

I need to get the `888888` value.

I found a way using multiple split but it's ugly.

I also think of using something like:
`line.substring(ind+"VERSION ==".length(), line.length()-10).trim();`

But the "blablabla" length can change..

Thank you.

---

Edit: It works using an hardcoded string like this.

But when I try to run it from the file I get this error:

```
test' is failed: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed: 
script1516208488151762512206.groovy: 4: expecting '}', found '' @ line 4, column 69. 
ne.contains('VERSION ==') 
^ 

1 error
```

Here is my code:

```
${groovy:
    String Ver
    def file = new File("C:\\test.cpp")
    def data = file.filterLine { line -> 
        line.contains('VERSION ==')
    }
    Ver = data.split("==")[1].split(",")[0].trim()

    logger.info(Ver)
}
```

--
I also tried something like this:

```
${groovy:
    String Ver
    def file = new File("C:\\test.cpp")
        while ((line = file.readLine())!=null) 
        {
           int ind = line.indexOf("VERSION ==")
           if (ind >= 0)
           {
               Ver = line.split("==")[1].split(",")[0].trim()
           }
        }
        logger.info(Ver)
    }
```

But I get same kind of weird error:

```
expecting '}', found '' @ line 9, column 58. 
("==")[1].split(",")[0].trim() 
^ 

1 error
```

:(

Comment: Two recommendations that may help resolve the syntax error: use `new File("C:\\test.cpp").eachLine { line -> ... }` instead of the `while` loop and use `ver` as the name instead of `Ver`.

Comment: Thanks, I found the issue of the weird error. Using ${ before groovy: was the issue with the interpreter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do as shown below:

```
def line = 'STATIC_ASSERT(VERSION == 888888, "blablabla");'
println line.split('==')[1].split(',')[0].trim()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I edited my first post, I have a weird issue.